# create expression with a dash/or ignore all values after the 5th digit

Tags: regex

I need to use an expression in a string to look for a range of postcodes

The expression I already have works when the postcode has 5 numbers

e.g.

Postcode range 30000-39999

```
String USAPostcodeExp = @"^[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$";
```

this works with the postcode 31234

but some of the postcodes have 5 digits a dash and 4 digits

e.g. postcode 31234-1234

and these are not been recognised from the script.

Only the first 5 digits are relevant to our needs

So how do I write it so either it accounts for the extra dash and 4 digits

OR it ignores anything after the 5th digit.

Comment: Do you also need to make sure that it's a valid postcode? I mean besides matching the first 5 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a word boundary to your current regex instead of using a `$`:

```
@"^[0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b";
```

Also, you mentioned the range was `30000` to `39999`, so shouldn't that be:

```
@"^3[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b";
```

Instead?

Shortened to:

```
@"^3[0-9]{4}\b";
```

The above will do the second option: ignore everything after the 5th digit (but still ensure that it is a 5 digit code within the required range).

If you want to match the additional part, you can use an optional group:

```
@"^3[0-9]{4}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$";
```

Comment: brilliant, yes my range example was not really correct as you pointed out, I am actually working from 00001 - 39999.  Your answer was brilliant and worked instantly - have been trying different connotations for 3 hours and going insane - should have asked sooner!  thanks so much!

Comment: @jacquisu Oh, okay then, change the `3` back to `[0-3]` in that case :)

Comment: As you were so quick with this one more question if I may, how would you handle the postcode range of from 80000 - 93599

Comment: @jacquisu Hmm, well regex is not very suited to check ranges, but there are tools online that can generate those regexes (I don't recommend using regex to check numeral ranges). For that range, [this tool](http://rahulchoubey.com/Offline/RangeREGEX.aspx) gives `((((8000[0-9])|(800[1-9][0-9])|(80[1-9][0-9]{2})|([1-9][0-9]{3}))|((9359[0-9])|(935[0-8][0-9])|(93[0-4][0-9]{2})|(9[0-2][0-9]{3}))))` (see how complex it is!)

Comment: wow I have been struggling to achieve this manually!  didn't know such tool existed!  you have been extremely helpful thank you!